# How do you build projects in Android Studio without Gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am looking to build a simple C math library using Android Studio. In theory, I could use CLion, but that only has a 30 day trial and there are some other little nice things that I like about AS (also, I'd rather just have one IDE installed instead of 2, for when I do app dev).  The problem is, when I create a new project, it creates so much cruft that I don't care about -

```
build.gradle
gradlew
gradlew.bat
local.properties
settings.gradle
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
app/build.gradle
app/src/main/java/blah blah
app/src/main/res/blah blah
app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
etc.
```

Ideally, I want to be able to set up a project where someone who just uses the NDK tools can build the binary and not have all of this extra Gradle stuff for building an app that doesn't exist.

Comment: Intellij IDEA has support Android development without gradle

Comment: How? Everything wants to look in app/

Comment: I too don't understand the excitement about gradle. It seems horribly confusing and convoluted. What should be simple, is instead of horrible overcomplex gobbledegook. I dread the day I can no longer avoid it.